# Display popup only when the user logs in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show the popup window when the user logs in to the site. That means when the user click on login button and it redirects to next page, that time the popup should appear. User able to access the background page after closing the popup. When the user tries to refresh the page, it should not show the popup. But the below code shows the HTML screen overridden on my background page.

```js
 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
     width : 710,
  height : 410,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,  
  draggable: false, 
    });  
  
    
  });
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 


.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    height: 15px;
    
 }
 button {
  outline:none !important;  
}
 
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal"></div>
<div id="dialog"  title=" ">
  <iframe style="position:absolute;Left:150" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="670" height="350" src="popUp.html" ></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How you have it now it will be triggered on document ready so even if the user is already logged in if a page refresh happens it will trigger it. There is no reference to the login action in your code anywhere, you want it to trigger at log in only correct?

Comment: You should have a callback function on the login button to trigger the popup, if you only want it to show it at log in. If that is what you want confirm it and I will gladly draft something for you

Comment: Provide more details about how your login process works. There aren't enough details for anyone to answer this properly

Comment: On client side, you have use cookies to store value for whether you clicked on button or not, then you can easily get to know whether to show popup or not. If on server side, you can create session for that.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please let me know if you want more info

Answer (score 1):

Capture the login button click event then trigger your popup like this

```
$(function() {   
  $("login-btn-id").on("click",function(){  
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        width : 710,
        height : 410,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,    
        draggable: false,   
     });  
  })
});
```

Comment: This will show popup each time, question is not to display the popup again on refresh.

Comment: This will only show always on login but once logged in it will not show on refresh. The code he shared will show always, even after logged in if the user refreshes, he was asking to show only on login if I understood correctly @Hemal

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP sessions for that.

When user logs in, you open a session

```
$_SESSION['popup']=1;
```

And this code will work:

```
if ($_SESSION['popup']==1){

?>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        width : 710,
     height : 410,
     modal: true,
     resizable: false,   
     draggable: false,  
    });
</script>
<?php

$_SESSION['popup']==NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

As you will redirect the user to another page after logging in, so using a callback in the login button click won't help you here, you should use something that preserves a state even when the page is refreshed and on document load.

**Solution:**

One tricky way to achieve this is to use *Cookies*.

When a user login and the first time your popup will open, set a cookie `logged` to `true` and test if this cookie is `true` don't show the popup.

And if a user logout, remove this cookie.

**Code:**

This is the edited code:

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

$(function() {
  var cookieValue = readCookie('logged');
  if(cookieValue !== "true"){
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        width : 710,
        height : 410,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,    
        draggable: false,   
    });
    document.cookie="logged=true";
  }
});
```